# How can I reshape the data of an numpy array storing sequence of color image (RGB),?

Tags: numpy, deep-learning

I have a numpy array in the shape [n_samples,color_channels*time_window, width,height] storing the data for seven frames of color image, I want to reshape it to [n_samples, color_channels, time_window,width,height] how can I do it?

Comment: Look into `numpy.reshape`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: shapes are tuples. You may try that, assuming A is your original array:

```
B = np.reshape(A, (n_samples, color_channels, time_window, width, -1))
print(B.shape)
```

Comment: Probably makes more sense to omit the -1, if the height is known